Does Dragonskin Armor Affect Ranger's Dual Wield?
My Ranger is dual wielding. 2e rules say I forgo the dual wield penalty if I wear studded leather. Where does dragonskin fit into this?


Where does dragonskin fit into this?

It doesn't. Assuming you mean dragon skin from the monster manual, it doesn't say.
If I remember correctly, it doesn't say anything about being equivalent to anything else, didn't say anything about interacting with "special" abilities like dual wielding or thieving and the Armor class was a variable, too, based on the dragon so even just "assuming" some equivalency based on stats is pointless.
You could release your inner rules lawyer and argue that since it says "studded leather or lighter", a dragon skin armour weights exactly the same, so it is neither studded leather, nor "lighter" strictly speaking.
As so much in early editions, the entry in the MM was never meant as a hard rule, but as a cool and fun idea for the DM to build on. Your DM can tell you what they think it will do in their world.
Personally, I think in my group we would have allowed it. I mean the group slew a dragon. Surely that justifies a reward slightly better than a studded leather armor you can buy in the next village.

That's what I was thinking about the weight. The manual says "studded leather or lighter," and it's the same weight as studded leather. I guess I wasn't sure it meant lighter as in weight or lighter as in protection.

It fits in Studded Leather armor description. Nvoigt answer is completely reasonable, but if nothing specific is said, the inverse is true too, and it is up to GM to interpret the rules. "Dragon armor is supple and non-bulky, weighing only 25 pounds." I see no reason to rangers and rogues cannot use it with no penalties, in our campaigns it was somekind of a goal of some rangers to be dragon slayers. In 3e, where the fixed descriptions reigns, it is just a masterwork armor from the type the armorsmith crafts (hide, banded, etc.), but in 2e you have too the unofficial rules from Baldur's Gate videogame, and I remember my half-orc using the shadow dragon hide armor and still being able to backstabs.

Yes, I think it's been the consensus that it's up to the DM in TT, but getting into video games based one 2E rules is a totally different thing. All of the video games based on 2E rules varied from the official ruleset in some important ways, so the way the OG Baldur's Gate implemented Dragon Skin Armor can't really be taken as evidence for or against.

I understand your point, there is some simplifications, like proficiences, but there is too a lot of gaps on rules in 2e, and Baldur's Gate I and II and Icewind Dale I, aside simplifications, are very similar in rules, the differences mainly filling the gaps. I don't know if the Black Isle game designers had consulting with the TSR game designers.

I think the important thing to remember about the Hasbro 2E games is that they came out at the very end of 2E when 3E was being released. TSR had been gutted and only a few people moved over to WoTC, so there wasn't anyone to consult; TSR ceased to exist in 1997. I think the 2E video games can be understood as being campaigns created by a DM who was okay taking liberties and interpreting the ruleset to make the experience fit it's context in the best way possible. And I think that is a good thing because a PC game is a very different experience from a TT game.
